# What are the plugins installed on Joomla script on this site

Tags: plugins, joomla

What are the plugins installed on Joomla script on this site:
http://www.josourmagazine.ae/english/
( style , models , extentions , plug-ins ... etc. )
thanks for any help
zuhair

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the source code and you'll have some ideas!